# Prepending GET parameter to permalinks with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, localization

I have a question about rewrite rules and WordPress permalinks. For the purposes of a localisation feature, I need to prepend a 'pretty' param at the beginning of all paths on a site. So for example, example.com/post-title would become example.com/en/post-title. To do this I was thinking of creating a rewrite rule in the .htaccess which would take a ?lang=en from the end of the url and transform it as described. Is this even possible with rewrite rules? And even if it is, would the permalinks in WP honour it or would they just revert to the link stored in the db for the post?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [WPML](https://wpml.org) or another plugin like this to work with different languages in WordPress. WPML will also solve your 'pretty' URL problem without rewrite etc.

Comment: Trouble is, due to issues with caching it's difficult for me to use any translation plugins. Also in my situation it's better to be able to just use .mo files from the theme rather than have translations managed from the DB.